# PHP - autocomplete with php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, autocomplete

I am working on an autocomplete script where i first read files from a local directory using php as shown below:

```
<?php
$file = glob('pages/*');
//var_dump($file); 

foreach($file as $value)
{
    $output = substr($value, 6, strlen($value) - 6);
    //echo($output)."<br>";
}
?>
```

the above script displays all the files in the 'pages' folder i.e pageone.html,pagetwo.html....

i then use a javascript file to dispaly a text field that when entered for example 'page', should show aome autocomplete options say 'pageone.html' or 'pagetwo.html' e.t.c

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = ["
<?php echo $output; ?>"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i combine the above php code with this js to a single php file

as shown, i try embedding the '$output' into the js 'availableTags' variable but when i type something on the text field, nothing happens..i'm sure it has to do with the php code embedded in the js so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$output` contains only a single value (last file in your list). You can create an array of files like:

```
$res = array();
foreach($file as $value)
{
    $res[] = substr($value, 6, strlen($value) - 6);
}
```

and pass it to javascript as: a javascript array (with [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) function)

```
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = <?=json_encode($res)?>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [autocomplete.js](http://autocomplete-js.com). It's more lite and easy to use that jQuery UI.